# Canvas - записать координаты в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, canvas, функции

Это холст, на котором можно рисовать что-либо мышью. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы сохранить координаты нарисованных линий в массиве. Для этого мне нужен цикл. Но при каждом новом действии все переменные обнуляются и вызываются заново. Так в данном коде alert(i) - постоянно выводит единицу "1", соответственно когда я добавляю координаты в массив, они всегда встают на одно и то же место и вместо накопления, просто заменяют друг друга.

Как можно записать нужные мне координаты в массив ?

```
window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.onmousedown = startDrawing;
  canvas.onmousemove = draw;
};

function startDrawing(e) {
  // Начинаем рисовать
  isDrawing = true;

  // Создаем новый путь (с текущим цветом и толщиной линии) 
  context.beginPath();

  // Нажатием левой кнопки мыши помещаем "кисть" на холст
  context.moveTo(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
};

function draw(e) {

  if (isDrawing == true) {
    var i = 0;
    // Определяем текущие координаты указателя мыши
    var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

    // Рисуем линию до новой координаты
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();


    var coord_arr = [];
    coord_arr.splice(i, 0, {
      x: x,
      y: y
    });


    i++;
    alert(i)
  }


};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно сохранять координаты линий, Вам нужно сохранять координаты курсора и рисовать по ним линии.

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', document_mousedownHandler );

const path = { coords: null };

function document_mousedownHandler( event ){
  path.coords = [];


  document.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', document_mousedownHandler );

  document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', document_mouseupHandler );
  document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', document_mousemoveHandler );
}
function document_mouseupHandler( event ){
  path.coords = null;


  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', document_mouseupHandler );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', document_mousemoveHandler );
  document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', document_mousedownHandler );
}
function document_mousemoveHandler( event ){
  path.coords.push( { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY } );
}
```

Все что Вам осталось, это вызывать метод `render` и в цикле рисовать по координатам.